# How to Determine a PCB's Power Requirements?

Tags: pcb, power, led

**Disclaimer**: I have very little (almost none, really) electronics experience.

---

I purchased a set of IR illuminator boards off of eBay. The only information that the seller provided was that the board had an operating voltage of 12 VDC and that the board has a built-in auto protection circuit that prevents damage from high voltage.

I have two questions. One directly related to this PCB, and one general:

1. How can I figure out how much current these boards will draw?
2. Suppose the seller omitted the required voltage information. How would I go about figuring out how much juice a certain board needs without frying it?

---

The board in question is sold by a lot of eBay sellers. [Here's](http://cgi.ebay.com/New-18-Infrared-LED-Lamp-Bulb-Camera-5mm-12V-/130388274468?cmd=ViewItem&pt=LH_DefaultDomain_2&hash=item1e5bbf2d24) one listing with decent pictures.

---

**EDIT**: Thanks for your answers everyone; you were all helpful.

Comment: Why don't you ask the seller?

Comment: @starblue: many sellers on eBay provide zero service, not even a single sheet of documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can measure the amount of current the board draws using the current measurement capability of a multimeter. If your multimeter does not have a fuse on the current input you should put one in series. You place the multimeter in series with either the positive or negative line of your power supply. I would use the negative line.

When first powering a device I would use a supply with a current limit. This limits
the current if there is a fault or if the vendor really meant 5V and not 12V, etc.

Did the vendor mention if the device has an internal current limit?

It is not clear what the "high voltage" protection is. It could be a transient protection
device that will not protect the device if you apply a continuous voltage that is
beyond the input voltage range.

It is not really practical to determine the input voltage specification unless you
have a reasonable idea what it is before you start. You will not be able to determine
the maximum input voltage reliably.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case of IR LEDs, you could count the number of LEDs wired in a series string. (Google "series versus parallel wiring" for details on what "series" means.) IR LEDs can tolerate a voltage in the range of 1.3-1.7 V per LED.

For a 5-LED string, you could start with 5 * 1.3 = 6.5 V and increase from there. They'll get brighter as you increase the voltage*. Eventually the LEDs will overheat and burn out. If you're willing to buy a few and risk burning them, you should be able to figure out the peak voltage a PCB can tolerate.

*(I'm eliding some details here-- the LEDs brightness is actually more linearly related to current than voltage, but you said you were new to electronics, so don't worry about that. I'm also presuming you have some sort of IR camera that can see the IR output.)

Answer (score 2):

1) Use an ammeter in series with the power supply to measure how much current the device uses.  You will have to break the circuit in order for this to work.  Breaking the circuit is not always easy.  You may need to cut the power supply wires in order to break the circuit.  Since you're a novice, I would be very, very, very careful with cutting the power supply wires.

2) If you do not know what voltage a device takes, try to follow the circuit from the DC power plug to the nearest regulator (it should be in close proximity to the DC power plug).  Google the part number, find the datasheet, and see what the minimum input voltage requirement is for the regulator.

Linear regulators require some extra room, so a 9V regulator might require 10V or more, which is why they would suggest a 12V supply.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the board there is not much there besides the LEDs and a couple of parts which I am guessing are resistors. It look like there are two groups of 9 LEDs and then a current limiting resistor. So measure the voltage across the resistors and use ohms law to work out the current. Each group should not pull more than around 50mA so I am guessing the board in total will be less than 100mA. Looking at a [data sheet for an IR led](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81012/tsal7200.pdf) for 100% on you should not exceed 20mA or you will be damaging the LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook it up to any 12V power supply, but it might not work. It won’t work if the board draws more current than the power supply can source. This might burn out your power supply, but not your board. Additionally most power supplies have over current protection that will shut down the supply if a short or over-current is detected. If you have a multi-meter and know the max current of your power supply you can measure the current draw of the board and if it is approaching or exceeds the max current of the supply then chances are you are going to need a bigger power supply. Try one with a higher maximum current, but make sure to keep the voltage at 12V

Comment: Thanks! How about if I didn't know it required 12 VDC? How would I be able to figure out the minimal power requirements for a board then?

Comment: Contact the manufacturer, but the voltage requirements should be written right on the part itself. One other way though I don't recommend it is to check some of the IC components that are tied directly to the power supply rails on the board. The component with the lowest voltage rating is the board supply voltage.